# Want to install VirtualBox Guest Additions on CentOS 7 but get a header mismatch

Tags: centos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kernel-modules, linux-headers

I try to install VirtualBox Guest Additions on a CentOS 7 VM.

I installed the prerequisites via

```
sudo yum install perl gcc dkms kernel-devel kernel-headers make bzip2
```

then I "inserted" the Guest Additions CD image and the Guest Additions auto runner came up and ran.

However the Guest Additions installation errored out with

> VirtualBox Guest Additions: Kernel headers not found for target kernel 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64.

For closer examination I issued the following commands in the Terminal shell of the VM:

```
$ ls /usr/src/kernels/
3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64
```

and

```
$ uname -r
3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
```

Notice the ddition caharcters `18.1` in the installed headers copared to what the kernel reports. I guess that is the reason why he Guest Additions installation fails.

**How can I fix this and install the Guest Additions?**

---

A few more details:

- **OS Version**: CentOS 7.7.1908
- **Guest Additions Version**: 6.1.6
- **EPEl Repo URL**: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

Comment: Please install `kernel-headers-$(uname -r)` and `kernel-devel-$(uname -r)` and check again.

Comment: Thanks @binarysta! That did the trick. Do you write it up as an answer I can then accept, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please install headers exactly based on your `kernerl release`.

`sudo yum install kernel-headers-$(uname -r) kernel-devel-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Do you know what causes this issue?  Is it an incorrect version of Guest Additions?

Comment: @what is the exact issue for you? basically vbox searches for `kernel-headers` and `kernel-devel` same as current `kernel` release, if it cannot find, it will fail.