# CentOS7 Can't install VBoxGuestAdditions because kernel headers not found

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox Version 6.1.8 r137981 and trying to get full screen desktop working.
I believe I need to install VBoxGuestAdditions.
I have Oracle VM VirtualBox Extenstion Pack 6.1.8r137981 added to the Extensions in Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager.
In Oracle VM VirtualBox under Devices I select Insert Guest Additions CD Image and run it.

I get:
[image: VirtualBox Guest Additions installation]

I read to check `uname -r` & it returned
3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64

Also `ls /usr/src/kernels*` returned
3.10.0-117.8.2.el7.x86_64

yum list shows:
[image: ersion 6.1.8 r137981]

I read the post, but I haven't been able to resolve my problem.

How can I resolve the above errors and get Virtual Box Guest Additions installed correctly?

Comment: Do not post images of text. Use the codeblocks. The kernel that you are running is older than what you have in `/usr/src/kernels`. Instead of `yum list`, add the output of `yum list installed | grep ^kernel` and `yum list available | grep ^kernel` to your question. Use the codeblocks instead of adding them as images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to install VirtualBox Guest Additions on CentOS 7 but get a header missmatch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582599/want-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-centos-7-but-get-a-header-missmatc)